# After upgrading to Mac OS X 10.11.4, I start seeing reports that certificates are invalid

Tags: certificate

I upgraded from Mac OS X 10.11.3 to 10.11.4 this week. After that, I found that, if I open some software e.g. Xcode simulator download page, or HMA client (a VPN Client), it reports some info: invalid certificates lie below:

```
"Could not download and install OS X 10.11.4 Documentation. The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net” which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

Or:

```
"System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0x5
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.RemoteValidation (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientContext context, AlertDescription description) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 "
```

And in system log, I also see:

```
17467     error=Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server        that is pretending to be “setup.icloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."                                               UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://setup.icloud.com/configurations/init, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect        to the server anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9807, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
17468         "<SecCertificate 0x7fdaba571060 [0x7fff7abb5440]>",                                                                                 
17469         "<SecCertificate 0x7fdaba551430 [0x7fff7abb5440]>"
17470     ), _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrust 0x7fdaba412b20 [0x7fff7abb5440]>,                   NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “setup.           icloud.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://setup.icloud.        com/configurations/init, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807}, httpStatusCode=-1, responseHeaders=
17471     (null)
```

However, if I create a new admin account on the same machine, issues are gone. I am not sure what's broken and I can I fix it.

Please help me fix it! Thanks!

Comment: saidly I dont know which cert is invalid, it just said cert is invalid, all I csn see is posted in question

Comment: I m outside, I will try when I get home asap. btw, I tried open the website in Firefox, Firefox says cert is good

Comment: allright, but I remember chrome is fine too. I will double check

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I updated my question with the cmd you want me to run. Is this the problem? setup.icloud.com:443 reports the same error code and message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37560/discussion-between-smokedispenser-and-wingzero).

Comment: alright, so after the chat, it may be better to move this question to SU.

Comment: Have you looked in keychain to see if there's existing certs?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I did, it's there

Comment: Have you tried keychain repair or creating a new keychain altogether?

Comment: tried create a new one and reset tI default, but no luck. how to repair? btw if I create a new admin account, issue gone, but I cannot move to the new account, too many stuff

Comment: You can rename or move ~/Library/Keychains and reboot.

Comment: is it any different? reset to default and move, rename, seems same to me. I m outside and will update later

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I just delete the whole key chain folder and let OS X build a new key chain folder, issues still the same.

Comment: What if you try logging out of iCloud in Sys Prefs, and log back in?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I fear I will not be able to login, not dare to try

Answer (score 1):

So after filing a bug on Radar, Apple folks told me to check keychain - preferences - certificates tab.

Changing CRL setting from `require if certificate indicates` to `Best attempt` or `off`, the issues are gone.

So it seems like, some CA certs under 'System Root' expired.

So we got two options:

1. leave CRL as best attempt (not sure how much it will weaken the system security)
2. delete the expired system root certs by following [security: SecKeychainItemDelete: UNIX[Operation not permitted] on OS X when trying to remove a system root expired cert](https://superuser.com/questions/1070664/security-seckeychainitemdelete-unixoperation-not-permitted-on-os-x-when-tryi/1071006#1071006).