# security: SecKeychainItemDelete: UNIX[Operation not permitted] on OS X when trying to remove a system root expired cert

Tags: macos, security

So I see some expired certs under 'System Roots' (not 'System'), so I want to delete them via cmd.

```
sudo security delete-certificate -c A-Trust-nQual-01 /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
```

However bash reports

> security: SecKeychainItemDelete: UNIX[Operation not permitted]

I entered the correct password for sudo for sure. How can I proceed?

OS: latest MAC OS X release, not beta.

Update:
I even tried with sudo su as root, still not work:

```
sh-3.2# security delete-certificate -c A-Trust-nQual-01 /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain 
security: SecKeychainItemDelete: UNIX[Operation not permitted]
sh-3.2# whoami
root
sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204899) (SIP) that prevents even `root` from modifying the contents of `/System` — you can toggle it by booting to the Recovery Partition (reboot holding Command-R) and then running `csrutil disable` command in the Terminal ([more details](http://ss64.com/osx/csrutil.html)). With SIP disabled, you can reboot and then your commands will be permitted.

Comment: thanks! I decided to change CRL to best attempt to work around

Comment: what is CRL ? how does it help with the above case ?

Answer (score 1):

Disable SIP in the recovery mode:

```
csrutil disable
```

Reboot and then:

```
sudo mount -uw /
killall Finder
```

Now you should be able to remove certificates.